# How to use Windows Start menu tasks in shortcuts on desktop

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I like the Windows 10 Snip &
Sketch tool. I know i can use it with Win+Shift+S keyboard shortcut.
But that doesn't work inside a remote desktop window (the screenshot will be done and saved on the host PC).

No problem, I can go to the remote's Start menu, type "snip" and then navigate to the "Take a new snip" task and execute it. (See screenshot)

[image]

But it's a bit cumbersome this way.
So What I have in mind is putting a shortcut to this action on the desktop of my remote PC.
But how to do it?

Comment: If your remote PC does not have the snipping tool installed (likely if its a Windows Server environment) it will not be possible to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desktop shortcut to the Snip & Sketch tool is simply a shortcut to:

```
explorer ms-screenclip:
```

Comment: I accepted a bit too quickly. This will indeed launch the snipping tool, but it immediately disappears again after the crop selection. No way to see the captured image.

Comment: You might be looking for `explorer ms-screensketch:`. `ms-screenclip` gets the snip to the clipboard only.